# Ansible Loop in Loop. Create interfaces for devices

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to loop within a loop for my playbook. Not sure how to format. My vars are:

```
    routers:
      - rtr: "ext-fw-{{ project_nummer }}"
        interfaces:
        - name: eth0
          networks: "vlan-ext-dmz"
          ip: "172.16.100.{{ ip_sub|int|abs }}"
          netmask: "/24"
        - name: eth1
          networks: "vlan-{{ project_nummer }}"
          ip: "{{ ip_subnet }}.0.126"
          netmask: "/26"
    
      - rtr: "int-fw-{{ project_nummer }}"
        interfaces:
          - name: eth0
            networks: "vlan-int-dmz"
            ip: "172.16.200.{{ ip_sub|int|abs }}"
            netmask: "/24"
          - name: eth1
            networks: "vlan-{{ project_nummer | int +1 }}"
            ip: "{{ ip_subnet }}.128.126"
            netmask: "/26"
```

Playbook:"

```
  tasks:
    - name: Debug routers vars
      debug:
        #msg: "{{ item }}"
        msg: "Hello {{ routers[0].interfaces }}"
      loop: "{{ routers }}"
```

What I try to do is loop over routers and within the "routers" loop I want to loop over the interfaces. Is that possible?

For each router I want to get the keys of the interfaces and their values.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements

Comment: So, in your case: `loop: "{{ routers | subelements('interfaces') }}"`, then: `Hello interface {{ item.1.name }} of router {{ item.0.rtt }}`

Comment: Thanks!! Did not know this was the right way to go but it is!

  tasks:
    - name: Debug routers vars
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.rtr }} {{ item.1.name }} {{ item.1.networks }}"
      loop: "{{ routers|subelements('interfaces') }}"